# Orbital integrals and cohomology of compactified Jacobians

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, nt.number-theory

I have heard it said that the backdrop to the Laumon-Ngo proof of the fundamental lemma was a series of reductions in which orbital integrals were replaced by their analogues over p-adic fields which in turn replaced by their analogues over $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$, which could be evaluated by counting points, or in other words by computing the cohomology of certain geometric objects.  These turned out to be the affine Springer fibers, which can be replaced by certain compact quotients, the compactified Jacobians of the spectral curves.

(Please correct the errors in the above!)

Anyway, my question was:

> > Is it possible to reverse this process and write an integral expression for the cohomology of the compactified Jacobian of some fixed (locally planar) curve?  Would the resulting expression be of any use, or too horrible to contemplate?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question (which I would love to see an answer to), but thought I would just mention that compactified Jacobians are a particular example of a Hitchin fiber (maybe you know this already).  Compactified Jacobians show up when working with $GL_n$ and while I think this is a really important case to think about, it is uninteresting in the case of Laumon and Ngo's work.  This is because the anisotropic locus of the Hitchin base is empty when $G=GL_n$ (or in other words, all endoscopic subgroups of $GL_n$ are Levi subgroups).

Comment: In case it wasn't clear from my desperate plea for corrections in the question, I know nothing about what is happening in Laumon & Ngo's work (& am interested in the Jacobians for independent reasons...)